# Create A Number Pattern

Tags: c++

I am trying to get this number pattern

```
Input: 7 
Output:  
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 1 
1 2 3 3 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 3 3 2 1 
1 2 2 2 2 2 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

But I can't figure out how to make it like that, any suggestion how to make that pattern??

My code so far :

```
int n, temp1, temp2,i,j;
cin >> n;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    for (j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
        temp1 = j;
        temp2 = n-j+1;
        if (temp1 < temp2) cout << temp1;
        else cout << temp2;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

The output so far is

```
 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
 1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what is the output so far?

Comment: Try writing down how you would construct this in english, then converting that to code.

Comment: The inner loop function of n needs work. As Eli wrote, define your function first, then code it.

Comment: @EliSadoff: Thank you for the clarification. This question ain't so bad now. Downvote converted to an upvote, and close vote retracted. Hint: your output is independent of `j`.

Comment: Is there a typo in the data?  There is a 3 in the "wall" of 2s.

Comment: oh sorry, there is a typo there

Comment: You are calculating `temp`s from `j`, shouldn't you try to do the same calculation for `i`?

Comment: I think you have had enough time on your own and need to experience Mr. Debugger and his infinite wisdom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code(working) might give you a better idea about the implementation.

```
int main() {

 int n;
 cin >> n;
 int arr[n][n];

//Numbers in the grid vary from  1 - (n/2 + 1)
 for(int i = 0; i <= n / 2; i++) {
    //Start filling the array in squares
    //Like fill the outer square with 1 first followed by 2...
    for(int j = i; j < n - i; j++) {

       arr[i][j] = i + 1;
       arr[n - 1 - i][j] = i + 1;
       arr[j][i] = i + 1;
       arr[j][n - 1 - i] = i + 1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: That's a really simple implementation. Thanks, now I know what I will do.

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that solves the problem is to divide this square into 4 quadrants:

```
---n-->
111|222 |
111|222 |
111|222 |
------- n
333|444 |
333|444 |
333|444 v
```

Each quadrant can be presented with limits:

```
1 - row <= (n + 1) / 2 && column <= (n + 1) / 2
2 - row <= (n + 1) / 2 && column > (n + 1) / 2
3 - row > (n + 1) / 2 && column <= (n + 1) / 2
4 - row > (n + 1) / 2 && column > (n + 1) / 2
```

Then every quadrant has to be divided into two slices

```
\  |  /
 \ | / 
  \|/  
-------
  /|\  
 / | \ 
/  |  \
```

These diagonals can be described using equations:

```
column_index = row_index
column_index = (n + 1) - row_index
```

Right now you just have to check if current 'cell' is under or above one of the diagonals, and use row or column index accordingly. Of course if row or column index is larger than (n + 1) / 2 then you have to adjust by subtracting it from n.

If you understand this, writing your own code shouldn't be a problem. It is good idea if you have to print everything immediately without storing it in some kind of array. If you can use array then @baymaxx solution is a lot cleaner.

It is my code if you would like to compare your implementation:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    for (int row_index = 1; row_index <= n; row_index++) {
        for (int column_index = 1; column_index <= n; column_index++) {
            if (row_index <= (n + 1) / 2 && column_index <= (n + 1) / 2) {
                if (column_index < row_index) {
                    std::cout << column_index << " ";
                } else {
                    std::cout << row_index << " ";
                }
            } else if (row_index <= (n + 1) / 2 && column_index > (n + 1) / 2) {
                if (column_index < (n + 1) - row_index) {
                    std::cout << row_index << " ";
                } else {
                    std::cout << (n + 1) - column_index << " ";
                }
            } else if (row_index > (n + 1) / 2 && column_index <= (n + 1) / 2) {
                if (column_index < (n + 1) - row_index) {
                    std::cout << column_index << " ";
                } else {
                    std::cout << (n + 1) - row_index << " ";
                }
            } else {
                if (column_index > row_index) {
                    std::cout << (n + 1) - column_index << " ";
                } else {
                    std::cout << (n + 1) - row_index << " ";
                }   
            }
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, I get it now how to do it